A canonical Matrix Product State that is not normalized?
So I have the following example of I think a left-canonical MPS of a PBC spin chain that is not normalized. For a single site, it looks like this:
$$A =
  \begin{bmatrix}
   \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}| 0 \rangle & |1\rangle\\
   \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}| 0 \rangle & 0
  \end{bmatrix}, A^0 = \begin{bmatrix}
   \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & 0\\
   \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & 0
  \end{bmatrix}, A^1 = \begin{bmatrix}
   0 & 1\\
   0 & 0
  \end{bmatrix}
$$
If we take the canonical condition, it holds
$$\sum_{i=0}^1 (A^i)^\dagger A^i = (A^0)^\dagger A^0 + (A^1)^\dagger A^1 = I,
$$
however if we trace out $A^{\otimes n}$ and take the inner product to normalize, i.e. for $A^{\otimes 2}$
$$A^{\otimes 2} = \begin{bmatrix}
  \frac{1}{2}| 00 \rangle + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}| 10 \rangle & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}| 01 \rangle\\
  \frac{1}{2}| 00 \rangle & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}| 01 \rangle
  \end{bmatrix}\\
Tr(A^{\otimes 2 \dagger} A^{\otimes 2}) = Tr\begin{bmatrix}
   \frac{1}{4}\langle 00 | 00 \rangle + \frac{1}{2}\langle 10 | 10 \rangle & \frac{1}{2} \langle 01 | 01 \rangle\\
   \frac{1}{4} \langle 00 | 00 \rangle & \frac{1}{2}\langle 01 | 01 \rangle
  \end{bmatrix} = 1.25.
$$
I tried doing SVD and followed the guide by Schollwoeck, but it gives the same MPS. Am I doing something wrong or misunderstanding something here? I thought that if I find a left-canonical form of an MPS it will always be normalized so long that I keep multiplying it to the right, and in this case, there being only 1 tensor and that it is PBC, means left or right shouldn't matter at all? If someone could help me with this I would really appreciate it! Thank you!

What precisely do you think should hold regarding canonical MPS and their normalization? What is the  role played by the boundaries?

Also, what you claim to be the trace on 2 sites, why should this be correct? -- Why do you say "and in this case it left or right shouldn't matter at all?"

The boundary here is PBC, which is why I took the trace. Because there's only one tensor for all sites, I think whether I contract it from the left or right leg it would still be normalized. I understood an MPS being left-canonical (satisfying the above condition) mean if I contract the tensors at each site, with new tensors being added to the right of the old ones, then the state would stay normalized. But when I take the inner product, the norm is 1.25.

But I'm very new to this so I could be wrong, please feel free to correct me. I have added the fact that the MPS is PBC and other things for clarity. Thank you!

You have to contract the left part from the left and the right from the right. One side will not give the identity.
